# How to silent Install chrome extension on Windows 10 Technical Preview without using a developer version of chrome.

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store, windows-10

I have a problem getting a chrome extension to work on Windows 10 Technical Preview. I have this extension hosted in Chrome Web store. However when my i run the .exe on my pc, which is supposed to install a client on the pc and an extension on chrome, i cannot see the extension in the chrome extensions.

But when i use the developer version of chrome, i can see the browser prompting me to accept/disable the extension.

What am i missing here? I am pretty new to chrome plugins. Any suggestion/help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Chrome (unfortunately) no longer allows private or local crx files to be installed as extensions. You must host it on the Google Chrome app store. From within the store you can make it private to a specific domain, or limit the app to only those within a Google group (they must use their Google account for access to the install).

Deployment of plugins that work within our intranet has suddenly become a major pain. I'm really surprised they couldn't come up with a better solution for this.

https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2663860?hl=en

Comment: Or fortunately depending on your security/privacy concerns.